# Spring org.springframework.core.env.Environment or @Value giving null

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, properties

I am trying to load properties through `org.springframework.core.env.Environment` in my Automation project. But I am getting Environment as null. Following is my configuration.

Dependencies in pom:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

`details.properties` : Placed under src/main/resources

```
group=RandomCheck
varry=RandomMonth
check=RandomDay
```

Property configuration class - TestProperty.java

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:details.properties")
public class TestProperty{
    
    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Test
    public void testPro(){
      System.out.println(env.getProperty("group"));
    }
}
```

After executing this JUnit test I am getting null pointer because of Environment. Am I missing any configuration here or doing something wrong?

I tried reading with application-context help of context:property-placeholder and @Value. Value is also returning null. Can someone help on this? Thanks.

Comment: I am guessing the issue is with the directories structure. This `@Configuration` in Test folder isn't going to be picked up by the `@ComponentScan` that is located in java folder. If that is the case solution would be to move TestProperty to Java folder and use `@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestProperty.class)` above the test class to pick it up

Comment: Nope. `TestProperty.java` is in src/main/java directory only

Comment: can you show me the class with you `public static void main`?

Comment: This isn't a test so it simply won't work. Also stop mixing jars from different versions of Spring that will bite you in the near future leading to weird issues.

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes. I modified all versions to 4.3.2.RELEASE for now - Edited. And how can I make work? Am I missing any other configuration?

Comment: You should write a test not a configuration class with a test method. I suggest a read of the testing chapter of the Spring Reference guide.

Answer (score 2):

You mixing your `src` and `test` environments. Instead of using `@Test` try using `@PostConstruct`.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:details.properties")
public class TestProperty{
    
    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @PostConstruct
    public void testPro(){
      System.out.println(env.getProperty("group"));
    }
}
```

And for the Unit Test for this class:

```
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource("classpath:details.properties")
public class TestPropertyTest {
    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Test
    void unitTest() {
      // test stuff
    }
}
```